# Compare network/mask to another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to check if a network/mask is part of another network/mask.

For example, check if `192.168.1.0/30` is part of `192.168.1.0/24`, and print either True or False.

I checked the `ipaddress` module, but unfortunately it only check for overlaps

Answer (score 0):

You can do that calculation with the [ipcalc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipcalc) module:

**Code:**

```
import ipcalc

network1 = ipcalc.Network("192.168.1.0/30")
network2 = ipcalc.Network("192.168.1.0/24")
print network1.check_collision(network2)
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

The [Documentation](http://ipcalc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a bit thin, but the module is only one file with two classes, so it is easy enough to inspect.